# How can I detect when a text area loses focus and keep it from losing focus when a particular element is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a text area `#ta` with a list `#ac-list` underneath that's used for auto complete:

```
<div id='container'>
    <textarea id="ta" name="god" rows="20"></textarea>
    <ul id='ac-list' style='visibility:hidden'></ul>
</div>
```

When the text area loses focus, I'd like to hide `#ac-list`. So I call jquery's `blur` on the text area:

```
$('#textarea').blur(function () {
    $('#ac-list').css('visibility', 'hidden');
})
```

This works, but I'd like to add the constraint that the text area shouldn't lose focus when the user clicks on `#ac-list`. How can I go about this?

Comment: You mean you want to the textarea not lose the Cursor when you manage `#ac-list`? This is not possible. I think you should hide `#ac-list` when users click on it or out of it and then focus in textarea again.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? This is just a workaround. The time taken for blur on textarea and to focus on the li item varies to different computers.

HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
    <textarea id="ta" name="god" rows="20"></textarea>
    <ul id='ac-list'>
        <li>dsfd</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var textAreaBlur = null;

$('textarea').blur(function () {
    textAreaBlur = new Date();
});

var clickTimes = 0;
$("#ac-list > li").click(
    function() {
        if((new Date() - textAreaBlur) < 200) {
            $("#ta").focus();
            $(this).text("dsfd" + ++clickTimes);
        }
    }
);
```